# Loading a widget in an iframe in Google Hangouts

Tags: google-hangouts

I want to include something like this [redditTV widget](https://github.com/octatone/reddit.tv/blob/master/index.html) in my Google Hangout.

Here's my `hangouts` folder in the `public` directory of my site:

[image]

I haven't modified the structure from the standard except adding the `redditTV` folder in the `static` folder.

In my `app.xml` I took a blind stab and tried:

```
      <iframe src="./redditTV/reddittv.html"></iframe>
```

However, I get this error in the iframe:

[image]

Here's the console log error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
https://ts6d5n5om59gt6cin9c39faccjf890k5-a-hangout-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/redditTV/reddittv.html
```

So the root of the google hangout is:

First, does anyone know if I can even insert a widget like this in an iframe in my Hangout app?

Second, how do I structure the files so that the Hangouts server can find them?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was simple enough. I just had to host the widget on my server and use that as the iframe src.